# Cache-Control: no-store for all aspx and MVC controllers

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, iis, iis-7, browser-cache

I have a Asp.Net web project consisting of both ASPX pages and MVC Controllers.
I need to make sure all .Net related request like request to any .aspx page or any controller/action should never be cached by any browser.
The response header should contain below cache header

```
Cache-Control:no-cache, no-store, no-transform
```

Also all the static files should be cached as it as (default behavior)

I am looking for any web.config related solution to this problem.

Comment: You can add `[NoCache]` attribute or use `HttpContext.Current.Response.Cache.SetNoStore();` in your layout to disable caching.

Comment: [NoCache] where is this attribute present in MVC?